# Using cURL to read from https response

Tags: php, curl, https

I am using the following code to access a URL (the URL uses the https protocol, and has a valid certificate)

```
// Initialize session and set URL.
$url = https://my url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But the output i get is this:

> Failed: Error Number: 60. Reason: SSL certificate problem, verify that
>   the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Can somebody please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'

```
$res = curl_init ('url');
curl_setopt($res,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$out = curl_exec($res);
curl_close($res);
echo $out;
```

for more info read [this](http://ademar.name/blog/2006/04/curl-ssl-certificate-problem-v.html)

Comment: thanks, as for as i can understand, the code snippet you provided will again SSL certificates? am I right?

Comment: @NewBee yes, n wt u want ? anything else ?

Comment: thanks, i am trying to learn things, now i will try to Parse the output and save it in XMl, trying to learn , learn and learn, thanks for the help boy...

Comment: i will be very thankful to you if you provide me guideline for converting the output to XML, don't give me the code, just tell me the steps required..will try to do the coding myself, and if problem found, will tease you people again :P

Comment: ok; but if you find the answer correct; mark that as correct instead of any thanks

Comment: @NewBee read about xmlencoding from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp and use this php function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the guideline, how can i add SSl certificate in it? to avoid the conflict?